# How to register SAP Business One DIAPI in AppService in Azure

Tags: sap-business-one-di-api

I have an ASP.NET Core web API project that locally works fine with interop.SAPbobsCOM because I have in my machine all installed and registered but when I publish it in App Service in Azure I get this error

An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.System.InvalidOperationException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID

Any idea how to register this in my App Service?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is happening becase there is no SAP B1 DI API installed, But I think that's not possible with azure app service.
Good option would be to use Service Layer instead of DI API.

Answer (score 1):

service layer is the best option for web integration project for sap business one